# How do I show results one at a time using XSLT (e.g. XML included)

Tags: xml, xslt, google-search-appliance

I'm creating a new XSLT for a Google Search Appliance and I've come across a problem that I've not been able to solve.

My search.xml has the following structure:

```
<GSP>
<ENTOBRESULTS>
  <OBRES>
    <MODULE_RESULT>
      <Field name="fullname">Dave Smith</Field>
      <Field name="title">Job title</Field>
      <Field name="telephonenumber">00000000</Field>
    </MODULE_RESULT>
    <MODULE_RESULT>
      <Field name="fullname">John Smith</Field>
      <Field name="title">Senior job title</Field>
      <Field name="telephonenumber">00000001</Field>
    </MODULE_RESULT>
  </OBRES>
</ENTOBRESULTS>
</GSP>
```

And the XSLT i've created looks like the following:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/GSP/ENTOBRESULTS/OBRES/MODULE_RESULT">
  <dt>
    <strong><a href="#"><xsl:value-of select="/GSP/ENTOBRESULTS/OBRES/MODULE_RESULT/Field[@name='fullname']"/></a></strong><br/>
    <em><xsl:value-of select="/GSP/ENTOBRESULTS/OBRES/MODULE_RESULT/Field[@name='title']"/></em>
  </dt>
  <dd><xsl:value-of select="/GSP/ENTOBRESULTS/OBRES/MODULE_RESULT/Field[@name='telephonenumber']"/></dd>
</xsl:for-each>
```

The problem I'm seeing is that the results are rendered in the following manner:

```
<dt><strong><a href="#">Dave SmithJohnSmith</a></strong><br/><em>Job titleSenior job title</em></dt>
<dd>0000000000000001</dd>
```

Making them look like this, in the browser:

> Dave SmithJohn Smith
>
> Job titleSenior job title
>
> 0000000000000001

Can anyone help me shine any light on this problem? I've a feeling it's a very basic XSLT error, and I'm not really an XSLT expert.

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `for-each` changes the context node so inside of the `for-each` you should respectively want to use a relative expression e.g.

```
<xsl:for-each select="/GSP/ENTOBRESULTS/OBRES/MODULE_RESULT">
  <dt>
    <strong><a href="#"><xsl:value-of select="Field[@name='fullname']"/></a></strong><br/>
    <em><xsl:value-of select="Field[@name='title']"/></em>
  </dt>
  <dd><xsl:value-of select="Field[@name='telephonenumber']"/></dd>
</xsl:for-each>
```